# Reapplying UK General Visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, family

My visa application has been rejected, due to lack of financial evidence clarity.This time I am getting a letter from my uncle that I will stay 5 days with him and the other 5 days in London. My purpose of visit is General Tourism and visiting my uncle. In the previous application I did mention that I will meet my uncle but I showed a hotel booking in London for 10 days.Also I will be travelling with my wife and 3 kids, aged 9,7 and one year. Now I am confused shall I apply for General Visitor or Family Visit. In 2012, I was sponsored by same uncle and I did got a family visit visa. 
KIndly advice the type of visa I should apply for.

Comment: The family visitor visa does not exist any more.  In fact, neither does the general visitor visa.  You need to apply for the visitor (standard) visa.

Comment: @GayotFow can you turn this into an answer, perhaps?

Comment: @MarkMayo, I'm on it like a bonnet!

Comment: @MarkMayo, can you check it now?  It's a very standard type of answer for this very standard type of situation :)  The OP generated this question last spring, hopefully everything worked out for him. :)

Comment: @GayotFow yeah, but I figure it's worth answering for other users too.

Answer (score 2):

There was a rule change in the [Immigration Act 2014](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/22/contents/enacted) that affects your decision...

To qualify as a family visitor, your sponsor must be immediate family or in the direct ascendent/descendent line.  So an uncle does not meet that criteria.  When you fill out the first part of the application, you can set it so it looks like this...

[image]

And then explain that your uncle is providing third party support in accordance with [V 4.3 (a) of the rules](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/22/contents/enacted)...

[image]

Your uncle needs to submit all of the financial evidence listed in the [supporting documents guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf).

I suggest that the guidance be studied carefully before submitting your application.